# How to regex a string representig a city or its postal code with accent?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a code of java allowing to show a list of cities depending on the name of the city or its postal code:

I wrote many expressions but they didn't work 100%.
This is my last expression:

```
([A-Z_]+)(:)([0-9]+)
```

The expression should match a city name : it could be : `Lonéy' ed` or its code postal `57000`

Does anyone have an idea how to improve my expression?

Thanx.

Comment: Try `(\p{Lu}[\p{L}\s'-]*):(\d+)` (double the backslashes in a Java string literal).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thnx but no, it doesn't work, by the way, how to limit digits to 5? because a postal code is composed of 5 digits

Comment: is there a space in your example?

Comment: Yeap, it could be composed of two words likes Las Vegas

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? [It **works very well**](http://ideone.com/UWIRvG), and more - it works much better than [the one you accepted](http://ideone.com/kGYU67). I just added `\p{M}` to handle diacritics, and the llimiting quantifier `{5}` to match 5 occurrences of `\d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Java7 you can do the following :

`Pattern.compile("([\\p{Alpha} '-_]+):(\\d{5})", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS)`

Keep adding connecting characters (here [ '-_]) to cater for all your needs.

The pattern doesn't make any assumptions about the case of the name of a place as in some non-Latin scripts there are no cases.

EDIT: added 5 digits postal code detection and a SPACE for name detection

Comment: It seems working, could you explain your expression please? and if `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` includes accented characters?

Comment: It will include all possible diacritics (accented characters) from all languages as well as non-Latin script letters.

Comment: Btw, `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` is a modifier flag not a character class. Please refer to Java API for `Pattern` class.

Comment: This regex does not match diacritic symbols in precomposed/multibyte characters. Also,  this `([\\p{Alpha} '-_]+)` does not work the way one may think it does.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew very interesting! Should it therefore be `([\\p{Lu}\\p{L}\\s'-]+)` ?

Comment: See my answer. I added all the details.

Comment: nice, one would think that a pattern matching a word would be simple. Thanks @WiktorStribiżew!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using

```
"(?U)(\\p{Lu}[\\p{L}\\p{M}\\s'-]*):(\\d{5})\\b"
```

It means:

- `(?U)` - a `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` inline flag that makes `\b` word bounsary and `\d` digit character class Unicode aware in the pattern
- `(\\p{Lu}[\\p{L}\\p{M}\\s'_-]*)` - Group 1 capturing:

  - `\\p{Lu}` - an uppercase Unicode letter
  - `[\\p{L}\\p{M}\\s'_-]*` - 0 or more characters that are either Unicode letters (`\\p{L}`), diacritics (`\\p{M}`), whitespace (`\\s`),  `'`, `_` or `-` (NOTE that the hyphen must be at the end of the character class so that it could be treated as a literal hyphen)
- `:` -  a literal colon
- `(\\d{5})` - (Group 2) five digits
- `\\b` - a word boundary so that we only match 5 digits not followed with a word char (not 5 digits in a 110 digit substring), can be replaced with `"(?!\\d)"`

See [Java demo](http://ideone.com/UWIRvG):

```
String s = "Lonéy' ed:57000";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?U)(\\p{Lu}[\\p{L}\\p{M}\\s'-]*):(\\d{5})\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); 
}
```